OnClick Function Not Working for DataTable
I have following code for lightningDataTable in LWC Component
<div style="border-top:1px solid #e6e9ef; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:6px;">
                    <lightning-datatable data={recordsToDisplay} class="boss_datatable_style" columns={columns}
                        key-field="id" sorted-by={sortBy} sorted-direction={sortDirection} onsort={doSorting}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction} onrowselection={handleRowSelection}>
                    </lightning-datatable>
                </div>

And in the JS File I am trying to open Modal on click of column Name but on click function is not working , can anyone please advise.
this.OpenModal is not working, I mean its not opening the modal.
this.columns.forEach(col => {
                    if (col.fieldName === 'Name') {
                        col.type = 'button';
                        col.typeAttributes = {
                            label: { fieldName: 'Name' },
                            variant: 'base',
                            onclick: (event) => {
                                this.openModal();
                            }
                        };
                    }
                });

I did tru with onclick but its not working
Also I tried with URL approach i.e
this.columns.forEach(col => {
    if (col.fieldName === 'Name') {
        col.type = 'url';
        col.typeAttributes = {
            label: { fieldName: 'Name' },
            target: '_self', // Open in the same tab
            tooltip: 'Click to open modal1',
            onclick: (event, row) => {
                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action of clicking the link
                this.openModal1(); // Execute openModal1 function
            }
        };
    }
});

but no luck

You can use the handleRowAction(event) to detect when the button is pressed:
if(event.detail.action.name === 'openModal') {

Make sure you provide a name on the typeAttributes property of the column so you can detect the button.

Attribute types mentioned for type button in salesforce documentation are disabled, iconName, iconPosition, label, name, title, variant. onclick is not mentioned in the documentation.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation
I thing you can try is changing onClick to small letter onclick if that works. But as per documentation, it don't support onclick.
You can extend lightning-data-table and create a custom data-table to handle this scenario.

updated the Question

I have used handleRowAction(event) {
this.openModal1(); on my lightning datatable.
